# how to left join two dataframe whose key is a dtype object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When trying the following:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.merge(overall_df['Locations'], job_catalog, how='left', on='job_code')
```

The corresponding join to `overall_df` returns a column full of `NaN`, when it is a column of strings, note that the key column is `job_code`.

Here's the structure of the main df:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 18207 entries, 0 to 18206
Data columns (total 12 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------         --------------  -----  
 0   Location       18207 non-null  object 
 1   Professionals  18207 non-null  int64  
 2   1y growth      17485 non-null  float64
 3   Job posts      18207 non-null  int64  
 4   Hiring demand  3757 non-null   object 
 5   Female         1161 non-null   object 
 6   Male           1161 non-null   object 
 7   Gender gap     1161 non-null   object 
 8   Top Employer   14157 non-null  object 
 9   report_name    18207 non-null  object 
 10  job_code       18207 non-null  object 
 11  country        18206 non-null  object 
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2), object(9)
memory usage: 1.7+ MB
```

And the one to be left joined:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 488 entries, 0 to 1054
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------            --------------  ----- 
 0   job_code          488 non-null    object
 1   job_title_intern  488 non-null    object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 11.4+ KB
```

How to perform this left_join with two dtype object keys?

Comment: joining on `object` is fine, so i guess it has something to do with the data. can you post some sample data that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are trying to merge a Series (`overall_df['Locations']`) with a `pd.DataFrame`. Take into account that your Series does not have the column `job_code`.

This should work:

```py
import pandas as pd
df_result = overall_df.merge(job_catalog, on='job_code', how='left')
```

If you think there might be a problem with your object key column, try cleaning it before merging:

```py
import pandas as pd

overall_df['job_code'] = overall_df['job_code'].map(str).str.strip()
job_catalog['job_code'] = job_catalog['job_code'].map(str).str.strip()
# Then you merge
df_result = overall_df.merge(job_catalog, on='job_code', how='left')
```